# Listview in android with toast message

Tags: android, android-listview

### I am trying to display items in a listview

- And onclick of list row display a toast message
- I am having the error

*I am able to display the elements in listview but on click of list item i am getting the error*

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String Names[]={"Mango","Banana","grapes"};

        ListView LV=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView1,Names);

        LV.setAdapter(adapter);

        LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="italic|bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LOG**

```
08-19 18:29:18.621: D/AndroidRuntime(692): Shutting down VM
08-19 18:29:18.621: W/dalvikvm(692): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.example.listviews.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:34)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-19 18:29:18.921: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 18:29:23.481: I/Process(692): Sending signal. PID: 692 SIG: 9
08-19 18:35:01.833: D/AndroidRuntime(726): Shutting down VM
08-19 18:35:01.833: W/dalvikvm(726): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.example.listviews.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:34)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-19 18:35:01.851: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Any ideas on overcoming this**

Comment: try this  `View view = (View)v.getParent();
                 TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()` in on List item click

Comment: use v.findViewById(R.id.textView1) then cast it to TextView since v is LinearLayout ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the logcat, You are getting class cast exception because you are trying to cast linear layout which is the root view (View v in this case) for your listitem to a TextView.

What you should be doing is as follows:

```
LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            //here v is your ListItem's layout.
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            String Names[]={"Mango","Banana","grapes"};

            ListView LV=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView1,Names);

            LV.setAdapter(adapter);

            LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    String itemStr = adapter.getItem(arg2);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),itemStr ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Help explain what you have changed and why, so the OP can learn from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s =(String) ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText();
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Your view is LinearLayout and not TextView.
You need to get this from your layout.

Change to something like:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)((LinearLayout ) v).findViewbyId(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```